# No redirection (rewrite) from one folder to another folder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

#### The full .htaccess file

Following is my full htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect index to homepage
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#prevent hotlinking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

#redirect galleries to portfolio
RewriteRule ^galleries/(.*)$ /portfolio/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

#prevent access to wp-config
<files wp-config.php>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</files>
</IfModule>
```

#### The directive in question

The following one is obviously the one in question:

```
#redirect galleries to portfolio
RewriteRule ^galleries/(.*)$ /portfolio/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

#### Expected outcome

If I go to `http://subdomain.example.com/galleries/headshots/` the server should redirect to `http://subdomain.example.com/portfolio/headshots/`

#### What happening instead

Nothing at all happens, I remain on `http://subdomain.example.com/galleries/headshots/`.

#### What I have tried so far without success

I added slashes at the end of both, the source and target - nothing changed:

```
#redirect galleries to portfolio
RewriteRule ^galleries/(.*)$/ /portfolio/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Also tried putting the directive on top, just below `RewriteBase /` - still no luck.

#### Notes

Note that this happens on a subdomain (see example url), although I don't think that has an impact on this behaviour.

This is happening on a Wordpress installation, but I have doubts it influences that. All the other directives seem to work fine (react on change).

**Edit** (from the comment reply to @Panama Jack): Both directories actually exist and are separate pages, but one is only setup as a script, if you like (other pages have to access its gallery).

Comment: To both of those directories work? is galleries a real directory?

Comment: Yes, both directories actually exist and are separate pages, but one is only setup as a script, if you like (other pages have to access its gallery).

Comment: Have your tried this in another browser or cleared your browser cache. I wonder if it's reading it because I would think this `RewriteRule ^galleries/(.*)$/` would have caused an error because that last slash is in the wrong location. it should have been `RewriteRule ^galleries/(.*)/$`

Comment: Thanks, @PanamaJack, you were right with your last sentence, see my answer... if you like, you can add an answer and I'd be happy to accept... ;)

Comment: Sure no problem. I added one. Glad it you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slash is in the wrong place. Change this

```
RewriteRule ^galleries/(.*)$/ /portfolio/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

to this

```
RewriteRule ^galleries/(.*)/$ /portfolio/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: is the slash required at the end of the 2nd part, after `/portfolio/$1`...? think I tried it without when it worked...

Comment: Nope. You can remove it if you want.

Comment: what would be the difference?

Comment: Nothing. preference. Whether you wanted it to appear with a slash or not.

Comment: Some people don't like slashes at the end of there urls and some dont care.

Comment: But to keep good SEO I would use one and stick with it. Slash or no slash don't do both. That prevents duplicates in search engine.

Answer (score 1):

In your rewrite rule the URL should start with a /.

Besides, the part `(.*)$/` is very strange: you are first looking for anything until the end and then adding a slash. Did you want to limit the rewrite rules to directories? Then why not including the trailing slash in the pattern: `(.*)/$`?

The below rule would redirect *everything* below `/galleries/`

```
RewriteRule ^/galleries/(.*)$ /portfolio/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```